# Why am I facing the API not connecting issue while trying to connect to the API to save the image using Winforms app dotnet

Tags: api, winforms

Why am I getting this Exception error.

[image: 1]

I tried to change the IP to local host and viseversa, but didnt get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this MSGraph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer build your query test. Also see the code snippets